# What are good resources for newcomers on entropy measurements?

Tags: resource-request, entropy, information-theory

I am starting on quantum computing and I got to entropy measurements, but that has me stuck because there seems to be a lack of resources for newcomers on those concepts and their utility. Does anyone know any good reference on them?

Comment: you " got to entropy measurements" and it has you stuck. What about them did you get to, and what is it about what you got to has got you stuck